# GeoXML3 not loading polygons when multipolygon present

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, geoxml3

I am implementing geoxml3 based off some examples geocodezip has provided. After implementing this it seems like the polygon objects are not being rendered but only the multipolygons from the KML.

From the documentation it seems like all that needs to be done is use a constructor for the geoxml3;

```
geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
                    map: map,
                    infoWindow: infowindow,
                    singleInfoWindow: true,
                    processStyles: true,
                    zoom: geoZoom,
                    markerOptions: {optimized: false},
                    afterParse: useTheData
                });
                geoXml.parse('http://serviceintelligencemap.dev.servicebench.com/MicroStrategy/plugins/GoogleMapViz/WEB-INF/xml/statesLayer6A2E05DB4BD8279D3EA05EBD921AF41223.kml');
            };
```

From here it reads in the entire xml and parses it.

Below is "working" example. It should render all states however it only renders the multipolygons;

http://serviceintelligencemap.dev.servicebench.com/MicroStrategy/plugins/GoogleMapViz/WEB-INF/xml/tst.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [KML is invalid](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fserviceintelligencemap.dev.servicebench.com%2FMicroStrategy%2Fplugins%2FGoogleMapViz%2FWEB-INF%2Fxml%2FstatesLayer6A2E05DB4BD8279D3EA05EBD921AF41223.kml).  You are missing spaces between the coordinates.

- KML validator (feedvalidator.org)
- [KML validator (feedvalidator.org)](http://feedvalidator.org/)

  ```
  <Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-114.63332,34.87057,0.0-114.63305,34.86997,0.0-114.56953,34.79181,0.0-114.48236,34.71453,0.0-114.44166,34.64288,0.0-114.38169,34.47903,0.0-114.29195,34.41527,0.0-114.14737,34.31087,0.0-114.26017,34.17212,0.0-114.35765,34.12866,0.0-114.4355,34.04257,0.0-114.49813,33.96372,0.0-114.51318,33.91285,0.0-114.52801,33.84446,0.0-114.49649,33.6969,0.0-114.5402,33.58709,0.0-114.61185,33.47131,0.0-114.72123,33.39691,0.0-114.68157,33.23376,0.0-114.62973,33.03255,0.0-114.48131,32.97206,0.0-114.46563,32.87408,0.0-114.58576,32.73487,0.0-114.63501,32.73137,0.0-114.69096,32.73946,0.0-114.71919,32.71943,0.0-114.71972,32.71875,0.0-114.9559,32.70253,0.0-115.47927,32.66605,0.0-115.50314,32.66438,0.0-115.80199,32.64163,0.0-116.0738,32.6211,0.0-116.19899,32.61112,0.0-116.3481,32.59913,0.0-116.46732,32.58952,0.0-116.61646,32.57725,0.0-116.75596,32.56578,0.0-116.82902,32.55977,0.0-116.95778,32.54863,0.0-117.02945,32.54234,0.0-117.06674,32.5395,0.0-117.22314,32.6209,0.0-117.30735,32.65404,0.0-117.34004,32.83452,0.0-117.37526,33.07321,0.0-117.57153,33.3123,0.0-117.71501,33.40862,0.0-117.81636,33.49087,0.0-117.94957,33.55979,0.0-118.06299,33.63031,0.0-118.34541,33.66343,0.0-118.51367,33.93905,0.0-118.62007,33.98697,0.0-118.74596,33.97556,0.0-118.87592,33.98382,0.0-119.22693,34.07434,0.0-119.33489,34.23687,0.0-119.56331,34.34814,0.0-119.73923,34.34275,0.0-119.90542,34.36437,0.0-120.12095,34.41671,0.0-120.24944,34.41798,0.0-120.42603,34.39674,0.0-120.56388,34.4893,0.0-120.6724,34.51999,0.0-120.70856,34.60609,0.0-120.683,34.7177,0.0-120.68251,34.80895,0.0-120.73438,34.9015,0.0-120.6942,35.03457,0.0-120.78292,35.11198,0.0-120.96025,35.24362,0.0-120.93094,35.37806,0.0-121.05951,35.4377,0.0-121.25103,35.60068,0.0-121.4561,35.81771,0.0-121.7489,36.14645,0.0-121.86514,36.20183,0.0-121.92971,36.25918,0.0-121.96481,36.32734,0.0-121.97196,36.37682,0.0-121.98576,36.42509,0.0-122.022,36.50891,0.0-122.04406,36.58872,0.0-122.06832,36.87495,0.0-122.27637,37.02483,0.0-122.4452,37.14967,0.0-122.47161,37.31479,0.0-122.56299,37.47338,0.0-122.57267,37.62752,0.0-122.63247,37.82781,0.0-122.78903,37.89376,0.0-122.89742,37.97575,0.0-123.08461,37.98809,0.0-123.12347,38.28431,0.0-123.18504,38.40068,0.0-123.3304,38.49991,0.0-123.49508,38.66066,0.0-123.7253,38.84412,0.0-123.76207,39.03837,0.0-123.80553,39.1249,0.0-123.84839,39.21873,0.0-123.89494,39.34835,0.0-123.88889,39.44394,0.0-123.83841,39.55492,0.0-123.87391,39.68453,0.0-123.9536,39.82699,0.0-124.06357,39.95662,0.0-124.2312,40.09338,0.0-124.42868,40.27564,0.0-124.47916,40.45264,0.0-124.33411,40.71898,0.0-124.1945,40.9617,0.0-124.2151,41.03142,0.0-124.24743,41.09222,0.0-124.25119,41.13756,0.0-124.21142,41.18092,0.0-124.17435,41.25705,0.0-124.19233,41.29199,0.0-124.23454,41.31575,0.0-124.23517,41.36383,0.0-124.14406,41.38412,0.0-124.15357,41.51075,0.0-124.22986,41.6897,0.0-124.41076,41.78831,0.0-124.31194,41.85879,0.0-124.32829,41.99807,0.0-124.32883,41.99833,0.0-124.11879,41.99703,0.0-123.96782,41.99625,0.0-123.79381,41.99569,0.0-123.62007,41.99984,0.0-123.51413,42.00086,0.0-123.2737,42.00197,0.0-123.03178,42.00302,0.0-122.78389,42.00388,0.0-122.64619,42.00482,0.0-122.40756,42.00869,0.0-122.18647,42.00755,0.0-122.00032,42.00397,0.0-121.81573,42.00262,0.0-121.70538,42.00077,0.0-121.6122,41.99933,0.0-121.51946,41.99827,0.0-121.43715,41.99738,0.0-121.36025,41.99668,0.0-121.26065,41.99759,0.0-120.97395,41.99336,0.0-120.76508,41.99387,0.0-120.60306,41.99309,0.0-120.30731,41.99313,0.0-120.19996,41.99443,0.0-120.00104,41.99514,0.0-119.99917,41.99454,0.0-119.99919,41.97905,0.0-120.00002,41.26742,0.0-119.99926,40.86934,0.0-119.99567,40.39719,0.0-119.99733,40.08934,0.0-120.00049,39.79567,0.0-120.0015,39.57782,0.0-120.00608,39.37557,0.0-119.9748,38.98156,0.0-119.76041,38.83427,0.0-119.43506,38.60904,0.0-119.00097,38.30368,0.0-118.51722,37.96065,0.0-118.22972,37.75309,0.0-118.04392,37.6185,0.0-117.79563,37.43715,0.0-117.31883,37.08441,0.0-116.87227,36.75057,0.0-116.37528,36.37205,0.0-116.08072,36.14577,0.0-115.89512,36.0018,0.0-115.65233,35.81231,0.0-115.36992,35.59033,0.0-115.11622,35.38796,0.0-114.82052,35.15341,0.0-114.63361,35.00195,0.0-114.63349,35.00186,0.0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></Placemark>
  ```

Comment: Bummer, for some reason thats how its stored in my database. Ill have to fix that

Comment: Yeah you are right.... http://serviceintelligencemap.dev.servicebench.com/MicroStrategy/plugins/GoogleMapViz/WEB-INF/xml/tst.html#